Why does my fluid explosion sim have odd artifacts?

Does anyone know why I get this odd geometric noise on my fluid explosion simulation? It's rendered at 256 samples with noise and .05 vorticity. Let me know if anyone has any ideas!

I think that's just the individual voxels. You'd have to up-res your simulation or increase sample count or decrease domain size.

@Lutzi
Hmm, that's interesting. I'll try increasing domain size. The resolution for the simulation is at 256 so I'm not sure why the individual voxels are so visible.
Thanks for the suggestion!

@Lutzi wrote "decrease domain size", not increase domain size. Apart from that it could be helpful to show your domain material settings. When the borders of the voxels are so strongly visible it is possible that your material setup produces visible parts where the density should acutally be 0.
